# Using DbFunctions I get error: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF 6 when I run this code even using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

```
var touches = analyticRepo.GetAll()
                          .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated.Date) == report.DateCreated.Date);
var test = touches.ToList();
```

I get this error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: This exception is thrown when the property getter returns a (presumably) modified backing field. E.g., the getter return _field.ToString().SubString(1,6) or something along those lines.

Comment: from System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the date up into a variable:

```
var reportDate = report.DateCreated.Date;
var touches = analyticRepo.GetAll()
                          .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated) == reportDate);
var test = touches.ToList();
```

Comment: I get the same error n exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: I don't understand what you have done here. Other than add an extra line at the start, it's the same code.

Comment: @GibboK sorry, didn't notice the `Date` on the first part.  Try the edited version.

Comment: @DavidG I pulled `report.DateCreated.Date` out of the lambda into a variable.