# Getting error when using DbFunctions to truncate DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, date

I'm trying to get a data filtering only by date (truncating the time). The field in database is DateTime.

As reference, I tried this solution that didn't work:
['Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083871/date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializers-entity-members)
where I should use the **EntityFunctions** that was replaced by **DbFunctions**, however, It still didn't work.

So I searched more trying to find some code that looks like mine, and then I've found this other link: [Using DbFunctions I get error: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912779/using-dbfunctions-i-get-error-the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported)
but I'm still getting the same error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Any suggestion?

My code:

```
var data = DateTime.Now.Date;
PostVisualizacoes visualizacao = db.PostVisualizacoes.Where(v => v.UsuId == usuario.UsuId && v.PosId == post.PosId && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(v.PosVisData.Date) == data).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i think truncating you have to make outside , not in Enfw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid that exception if you remove the `.Date` call from your `PosVisData` property:

```
var data = DateTime.Now.Date;
PostVisualizacoes visualizacao = db.PostVisualizacoes.Where(v => v.UsuId == usuario.UsuId && v.PosId == post.PosId
                                                              && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(v.PosVisData) == data)
                                                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Extract the date part from a `DateTime` property is the job of [`TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx) static method.